# AWS, permisos a Secret Manager para ejecutar Lambda para rotation

Tags: aws, amazon-s3, amazon

Tengo generado un Secret en **Secret Manager** y una **Lambda** encargada de actualizarlo.

Recibo el siguiente error cuando quiero seleccionar la lambda en **Rotation Configuration**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Failed to rotate the secret "ATLASSIAN_TOKEN".
Secrets Manager can't invoke the specified Lambda function. Make sure that the function's permission policy grants access to the principal secretsmanager.amazonaws.com.*

**Este es el rol en la lambda que quiero que ejecute Rotation en el Secret**:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Este es el Resource permissions de mi Secret**:

Siguiendo la documentación:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets-required-permissions-function.html
Da el siguiente ejemplo:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "LambdaRotationFunctionARN",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:SourceAccount": "111122223333"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

la cual me da el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿De que manera puedo solucionar este error?

Comment: y no te da más detalles del error? solo te dice que hay error de sintaxis?? ninguna pista adicional?

Comment: Solo eso @eferion , me parece raro por que es un ejemplo de ellos